# Map .NET Core response to Angular 5 Model

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I just want to do the simple mapping to an angular model I've made, but not successful with that. I have .net core on the backend and angular on the client side.  So, I am sending IActionResult from C# with a list of User object:

`public class User {
      public string Id { get; set;}}`

On client, i have service gor fetching users:

```
public getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this._httpClient.get<User[]>(url);}
```

I have also created simple User class on the client for testing:

```
export class User{
    id: string;
}
```

When I subscribe on this method, I get the list of all users with one property - Id (capitalized I) and not shown as angular User class but just like plain JSON file. I have also played with server/client class properties, no matter which properties I am expecting on client side model, I am always receiving plain Json from backend with backend class properties.

Any idea, what am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a JSON sample?

Comment: The formatter options has arguments for whether to capitalize properties.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is map a set of objects from .NET to Angular.

The Angular `http.get` does not map the returned response to objects, but rather only to an interface.

You instead need to manually map each element in the returned array into objects. Here is an example:

```
  productsClassInstance$ = this.http.get<ProductClass[]>(this.productsUrl)
    .pipe(
      map(products => products.map(product => {
        const productInstance: ProductClass = Object.assign(new ProductClass(), {
          productId: ProductId,
          productPrice: ProductPrice
        });
        return productInstance;
      })),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
```

In the constructor:

```
this.productsClassInstance$.subscribe(data => console.table(data));
```

In this code, I get an array of products. I then map each element of the array, creating an instance of the class using JavaScript's `Object.assign`. I then assign the properties of the object from the response to the desired properties.

The resulting Observable `productsClassInstance` emits an array of Product instances.

Did I understand the question?